# Manually position caption inside a figure

Tags: graphics, pdftex, captions, minipage, subcaption

How can I place my caption in the indicated arbitrary box in the below figure.

This is what I am using for now for my usual figures:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=162mm]{images/fig1.png} 
\caption{Some text}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Are those plots each a separate figure?

Comment: No. That is one figure.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=162mm]{images/fig1.png}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-50,-50){\parbox{.45\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Some text}\label{fig1}}}
\end{picture}

\end{figure}
```

then adjust the -50,-50 coordinates to put the caption wherever you like.

Comment: Doesn't the text within the parbox (that is my caption) wrap to the next line automatically? Why does ".45\linewidth" increase the spacing between "Figure. 1" and "Some text". I have the code in this link:   https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55256eadb4095469768723dc